# How can Scala receive multiple parameters in a method definition?

Tags: java, scala, variadic-functions

Java has:

```
public void someMethod(int ... intArray) { // question: what is the equivalent to "..." 
    // do something with intArray
}
```

how can I achieve the same functionality in Scala? That is, passing an undefined number of parameters to a method?

Comment: This is called "varargs" (for: variable arguments). Try searching for "scala varargs".

Comment: Just for the sake of google, ... is an elipsis

Comment: I needed varargs with 'by-name' variables. It seems that cannot currently be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707186/by-name-repeated-parameters

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
def someMethod(values : Int*)
```

Gives an array. Put the variable argument parameter as the last formal parameter.

Comment: Not an array in scala.

Answer (score 50):

Both Java and Scala have varargs, and both only support it for the last parameters.

```
 def varargTest(ints:Int*) { ints.foreach(println) }
```

From [this article](http://dgronau.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/varargs-in-scala/#), the difference is in the type used for the varargs arguments:

- array for Java
- Seq (Sequence) for Scala: it can be iterated and many methods such as collections foreach, map, filter, find, ... are available

The '*' stands for 0 or more arguments.

Note: if the parameter values are already "packaged" as a sequence, such as a list, it fails:

```
# varargTest(List(1,2,3,4,5))  
# //--> error: type mismatch;  
# //-->  found   : List[Int]  
# //-->  required: Int  
# //-->        varargTest(List(1,2,3,4,5))  
# //-->
```

But this will pass:

```
  varargTest(List(1,2,3):_*)  
  //--> 1  
  //--> 2  
  //--> 3
```

'`_`' is a placeholder shortcut for type inference.
'`_*`' is here applyied to a 'repeated type.
Section 4.6.2 of [Scala Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) mentions:

> The last value parameter of a parameter section may be suffixed by “`*”`, e.g.
>   `(..., x:T *)`.
>   The type of such a repeated parameter inside the method is then
>   the sequence type `scala.Seq[T]`.
>   Methods with repeated parameters `T*` take a variable number of arguments of type `T`.

```
 (T1, . . . , Tn,S*)U => (T1, . . . , Tn,S, . . . , S)U,
```

> The only exception to this rule is if the last argument is marked to be a sequence argument via a `_*` type annotation.

```
 (e1, . . . , en,e0: _*) => (T1, . . . , Tn, scala.Seq[S]).
```

Note bis: beware of the underlying type erasure of Java:

```
//--> error: double definition:
//--> method varargTest:(ints: Seq[Int])Unit and
//--> method varargTest:(ints: Int*)Unit at line 10
//--> have same type after erasure: (ints: Sequence)Unit
//-->   def varargTest(ints:Seq[Int]) { varargTest(ints: _*) }
```