# What is A* for method parameter?

Tags: scala

In below apply method what is "as: A*" ?

`List(1, 2, 3)` constucts a List of type : `Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil)))`

From reading the method code it appears that its a kind of syntax sugar for
multiple type parameters of same type ?

```
  sealed trait List[+A]
  case object Nil extends List[Nothing]

  case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
object List {
    def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] =
      if (as.isEmpty) Nil
      else {
        Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
      }
  }
```

If this is true should'nt this be also valid :

```
object List {
    def apply[A](asHead: A , asTail : A): List[A] =
      if (asHead.isEmpty) Nil
      else {
        Cons(asHead.head, apply(asTail.tail: _*))
      }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can Scala receive multiple parameters in a method definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438762/how-can-scala-receive-multiple-parameters-in-a-method-definition)

Comment: Hint: Google for "star in scala".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's a difference here.

When you declare `asHead: A, asTail: A`, `asHead` and `asTail` have obviously the same type. However, in the original code that uses `as: A*`, the type of `as.head` is `A`, and the type of `as.tail` is `Seq[A]` -- as can be deduced from the types of `head` and `tail`. Therefore, your code is not the same thing.

The declaration `A*` stands for "a variable number of parameters of type A", usually known as *vararg*. This is *similar* to a `Seq[A]`, but differ in the invocation:

```
apply(1, 2, 3) // A*
apply(Seq(1, 2, 3)) // Seq[A]
```

The counterpart to that is the `: _*` declaration when calling a vararg method with a sequence:

```
apply(Seq(1, 2, 3): _*) // A*
apply(Seq(1, 2, 3)) // Seq[A]
```

Comment: So would it be translated to JVM varargs (... in Java)?

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral "The declaration A* stands for "a variable number of parameters of type A"" from this statement does this mean that type A and type Seq[A] are
the same type  ?

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral List is a custom implementation, ive updated question

Comment: @blue-sky `A` and `Seq[A]` are not the same thing. I'm not sure what's the relevance of `List` being a custom implementation.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral it's a contrived example taken from book "functional programming in Scala"