# Scala: Is there a difference between method parameter String* and Array[String]

Tags: scala

Is there a difference between a method parameter `String*` and `Array[String]`?

Console:

```
scala> def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {}
main: (args: Array[String])Unit

scala> def main(args: String*): Unit = {}
main: (args: String*)Unit
```

Code 1:

```
object Example {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello")
  }
}

>> Hello
```

Code 2:

```
object Example {
  def main(args: String*): Unit = {
    println("Hello")
  }
}

>> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Example.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:126)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass scala Array into scala vararg method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064753/how-to-pass-scala-array-into-scala-vararg-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,

`String*` is a varargs, it takes in any number of Strings, which will be passed to the method as a `Seq[String]`.

`Array[String]` take in a single Array of Strings.

If you have a sequence of String that you want to pass as a `String*`, you cannot do so directly, but you can "splat" out the sequence to pass it in using the `:_*` type ascription.

```
def varArg(input: String*){}

val strings = Seq("hello", "world")
varArg(strings:_*)
```

Comment: So is `String*` a type or just how varargs is expressed in the console? How can I see in the console that it's passed to the method as Seq[String]? P.S. This old answer says it is passed as Array, did it change at some point to Seq? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1438796

Comment: @rapt I *think* it is a type but I'm not sure.  It is only usable as a method parameter either way.  The more upvoted and detailed answer form that question also mentions that it is a Seq.  You can also find out for yourslef in the repel by defining a varargs method and seeing what you get. `def test(args: String*) = args`.  We see that it returns a `Seq[String]`, the actual implementation depends though, when we pass in arguments the concrete implementation is `WrappedArray` but if we pass no arguments it is `Nil` (the empty List aka. `List()`)

Comment: I downvoted the linked answer for that error; Java uses arrays, Scala uses Seq. The repeated param has a type that is a Seq, http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters. The vararg itself is a type internal to the compiler, but we don't normally see that.

Comment: It would be cool if you could get the compiler to make a bridge to a varargs main, I don't know why they don't do that. Worth adding that this is what App is for.

Answer (score 2):

I went and asked on [the forum](https://gitter.im/scala/contributors?at=59a7919a210ac26920dcb4d4).

The annotation you want is `annotation.varargs`.

I had some inkling that they had that glue, but I never had a reason to use it.

Personally, I'd rather it were automatic for a `main` method, b/c obvious.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> object Main { @annotation.varargs def main(args: String*) =
     | println(args.size)
     | }
defined object Main

scala> Main.main(Array("hello","world"): _*)
2
```

OK, cool.

Comment: Probably my last input on SO.