# How to define scala function with undefined number and type of arguments

Tags: scala, list, types, variadic-functions

My function must take a list of values as argument, convert each one to string and add them to a list.
The values can be either `String`, `Int` or `Boolean`.

How to define a function with the flexibility to handle the different types?
Here is my initial function but as expected when i give int as argument, i get an type mismatch error

```
def test (s: String*): List[String] = {
  s.toList
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Scala receive multiple parameters in a method definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438762/how-can-scala-receive-multiple-parameters-in-a-method-definition)

Answer (score 4):

```
def test(s: Any*): List[String] = s.map(_.toString).toList
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i wanted. i've been able to trim and uppercase each string as needed.

Comment: If it's solved, can you mark the answer as solving please ? :-)

Comment: @C4stor No, I can't. ;) (Not sure whether the first commenter is notified in such cases)

Comment: Yes he is notified :-) I should have commented the question though, sorry !